# How do I delete the launch configuration of a deleted project if Eclipse(C++) refuses to automatically do it?

Tags: c++, eclipse

This all started when Eclipse stopped automatically creating the executable after debugging/compiling the program.

Answer (score 0):

Click in top menu on `Run` -> `Run Configurations...`. There all configurations should be listed and you can remove them. You can also check `Debug Configurations...`.